# can you use pydictionary in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to use pyDictionary in a google app engine application but I get an error. I don't get this error when I use it outside the google application. I've added it as a third party library (properly) so it actually imports it without errors so I don't know why.

here's the error:

```
searching.py", line 63, in   getkey assert isinstance(word.keys, object)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

and here's the code for that function:

```
def getkey(term):
    dictionary = PyDictionary()
    word = dictionary.meaning(term)
    assert isinstance(word.keys, object)
    results = word.keys()
    newresults = []
    for result in results:
        newresults.append(str(result))
    return newresults[0]
```

it works outside the app engine project, but not inside...

Answer (score 0):

You should go back and look at your the exception and try and understand what it is telling you.

```
searching.py", line 63, in   getkey assert isinstance(word.keys, object)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Let's trace it back through your code.

For that error to occur means that value referred to by `word` is None.

This means that the result of `word = dictionary.meaning(term)`

Is `None`.

So you should therefore look at what the value of `term` is.

Are you validating that `term` is meaningful anywhere ? If it is, what is the expected result of `dictionary.meaning(term)` and then investigate why you don't get the expected result.

Some basic debugging would go a long way here, helping you diagnose the issue.

Comment: thanks for the debugging tips... it helped. The objective is to get the meaning of the word stored in term.